# How to define an instance depending on some variable?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'll give code on Python, but it's doesn't matter.
I have a module `argument_parser` with dictionary and class:

```py
FORMATS = {
    'JSON': 'json',
    'XML': 'xml',
}

class ArgumentParser:
    # some methods
    def parse():
        """returns 'XML' or 'JSON' string"""
        return fomat
```

and a module with presenters -- `presenter`

```py
class JSONPresenter:
    # some magic


class XMLPresenter:
    # some magic
```

The problem is in dependency injection:

```py
argument_parser = ArgumentParser()
format = argument_parser.parse()

if format == argument_parser.FORMATS['JSON']:
    presenter = JSONFilePresenter()
elif format == argument_parser.FORMATS['XML']:
    presenter = XMLFilePresenter()
```

`if-elif` construction is ugly. If I want to add some other formats I'll must add more elif.
I could define the type of presenter in `ArgumentParser` class but I think semantically it is wrong -- it is not a filed of responsibility of this class. What should I do to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PRESENTERS = {
    'json': JSONPresenter(),
    'xml': XMLPresenter(),
}

argument_parser = ArgumentParser()
fmt = argument_parser.parse()
presenter = PRESENTERS[fmt]
```

Or, if you need a new presenter every time:

```
PRESENTERS = {
    'json': lambda: JSONPresenter(),
    'xml': lambda: XMLPresenter(),
}

argument_parser = ArgumentParser()
fmt = argument_parser.parse()
presenter = PRESENTERS[fmt]()
```